# Bubble Sort Trouble

Tags: c, debugging, sorting, pointers, bubble-sort

gcc compiles the following code without error.  I'm creating a bubble sort function that can be used with arrays of any data type (hence the function pointer).

It sorts the array of character strings (arr2) without a problem, however, I can't figure out why it won't properly sort the array of integers (arr).  I added a printf statement in the compare_long function to see what is going on.  It doesn't look like the integers are being passed to it properly.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define MAX_BUF 256

    long arr[10] = { 3,6,1,2,3,8,4,1,7,2};
    char arr2[5][20] = { "Mickey Mouse",
                         "Donald Duck",
                         "Minnie Mouse",
                         "Goofy",
                         "Pluto" };

    void bubble(void *p, int width, int N, int(*fptr)(const void *, const void *));
    int compare_string(const void *m, const void *n);
    int compare_long(const void *m, const void *n);

    int main(void) {
            int i;
            puts("\nBefore Sorting:\n");

            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {              /* show the long ints */
                    printf("%ld ",arr[i]);
            }
            puts("\n");

            for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {               /* show the strings */
                    printf("%s\n", arr2[i]);
            }

            bubble(arr, 4, 10, compare_long);      /* sort the longs */
            bubble(arr2, 20, 5, compare_string);   /* sort the strings */
            puts("\n\nAfter Sorting:\n");

            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {              /* show the sorted longs */
                    printf("%d ",arr[i]);
            }
            puts("\n");

            for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {               /* show the sorted strings */
                    printf("%s\n", arr2[i]);
            }
            return 0;
    }

    void bubble(void *p, int width, int N, int(*fptr)(const void *, const void *)) {

            int i, j, k;
            unsigned char buf[MAX_BUF];
            unsigned char *bp = p;

            for(i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                    for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) {     

                            k = fptr((void *)(bp + width*(j-1)), (void *)(bp + j*width));

                            if(k > 0) {
                                    memcpy(buf, bp + width*(j-1), width);
                                    memcpy(bp + width*(j-1), bp + j*width , width);
                                    memcpy(bp + j*width, buf, width);
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    int compare_string(const void *m, const void *n) {
            char *m1 = (char *)m;
            char *n1 = (char *)n;
            return (strcmp(m1,n1));
    }

    int compare_long(const void *m, const void *n) {
            long *m1, *n1;
            m1 = (long *)m;
            n1 = (long *)n;

            printf("m1 = %l and n1 = %l\n", *m1, *n1);

            return (*m1 > *n1);
    }
```

Comment: are you sure your long is 4 bytes?  It would be better to use sizeof(long) instead of hard-coding

Comment: Good point.  I'll try that.  One sec

Comment: Isn't bubble sort just simple swapping? Why are you coping memories?

Comment: That was the problem.  Thanks for the help.  I definitely should have caught that.

Comment: noMAD:  I needed to write a bubble() function that works with all data types.  Is there a way to do it without using memcpy?  It seems as though that would require adding different copy/swap functions for each data type.

Comment: Sure, why don't you just use normal swap and just use the `sizeof()` to determine the type of the array so that you can increment your pointer accordingly. There is no need for `memcpy()`. Also, you don't need different swap functions since you know the type of your data using the `sizeof()`. :-)

Comment: A couple suggestions that have nothing to do with correctness - the standard `qsort()` takes the element size and the number of elements in the array in the opposite order as your `bubble()` function.  I know it's not a serious production piece of code, but even so, I think it's a good idea that when you're doing something so similar to an existing, widely used function, you should use the same interface if reasonably possible (unless you can argue that that interface is flawed).

Comment: @noMAD - what do you mean by 'normal swap' for a void data type?

Comment: printf("m1 = %l and n1 = %l\n", *m1, *n1); %l -> %ld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANSI C spec defines long as a MINIMUM of 4 bytes (32 bits) but GCC is defining long as 8 bytes in your case. It is architecture-specific so you need to use sizeof(long) or one of the C99 types like uint32_t or int32_t if you want a specific size.